# AWS Iam with FIPS -- Credential should be scoped to a valid region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to connect to FIPS end points for IAM. The following is the test code which I am using.

```
AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endPointConfiguration =
        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("iam-fips.amazonaws.com", Regions.US_WEST_2.getName());
if (credentialsProvider.getCredentials() != null) {
    AmazonIdentityManagement client  =  AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
            .withEndpointConfiguration(endPointConfiguration)
            .build();
    GetUserRequest getUserRequest = new GetUserRequest();
    getUserRequest.setUserName("john@abc.com");
    System.out.println(client.getUser(getUserRequest));
}
```

When I try to get the user details of a user john@abc.com then It is throwing the following exception.

```
com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.AmazonIdentityManagementException: Credential should be scoped to a valid region. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: 617d-4213-a1ec-26aaf9145f8a; Proxy: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1879)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1418)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1387)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
    at com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.AmazonIdentityManagementClient.doInvoke(AmazonIdentityManagementClient.java:12948)
```

But for Iam FIPS end point there is no region available in the doc https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/fips/

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, we should use us-east-1 as the region for the IAM api calls in this case.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer! Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted. This helps in maintaining the quality of this website :)